# Python: Copying a list and removing an element at the same time

Tags: python

I am new to python and am trying to create a copy of a list without a certain element. This is how I am doing it at the moment:

```
oldList[1,23,4,3,5,345,4]
newList = oldList[:]
del newList[3]
doSomthingToList(newList)
```

I was wondering if there is a better more eloquent way to do this, instead of copying the list and then deleting the element in two lines?

Comment: Is the element excluded because of its index (i.e. "all elements except the third") or because of something more complex (i.e. "all elements except those that are larger than 200")?

Comment: Just the index. So the newList should be: [1,23,4,5,345,4]

Comment: dont use del, use remove instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
oldList[1,23,4,3,5,345,4]
newList = oldlist[:3] + oldList[4:]
doSomthingToList(newList)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> oldList = [1,23,4,3,5,345,4]
>>> newList = [x for i, x in enumerate(oldList) if i != 3] # by index
>>> newList
[1, 23, 4, 5, 345, 4]

>>> newList = [x for x in oldList if x != 4] # by value
>>> newList
[1, 23, 3, 5, 345]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with 'slicing':

```
>>> oldList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> newList = oldList[:2] + [oldList[3:]
>>> newList
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the built-in function [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#filter)

```
oldList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
newList = filter(lambda number: number != 3, oldList)

# newList == [1,2,4,5]
```

`filter`'s arguments are `function, iterable`.  It applies the function you give it to every element of the iterable and returns a list of the elements that the function returns True on.